# $.AJAX Post not working in JS but works in Advanced Rest Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, http-post

I'm having an issue with my JavaScript being able to contact the HttpPost service. I can access the same signature using the "Advance Rest Client Application" for chrome. However when I run my code in Console in Chrome I am unable to reach the service. Any thoughts? What am I missing from the signature on one vs the other? Please let me know if you need any more information.

JS AJAX Request (Stuck in Pending status)

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://local/r/GetSettings',
        data: '[{"SourceId":7,"DataType":0},{"SourceId":5,"DataType":1}]',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
        },
        error : function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
            console.log("ERROR. not working", error);
        }
    });
```

C# Service

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSettings(List<Source> sources)
    {
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = "{}",
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

     }
```

Advanced Rest Client Application (Success in returning {})

```
    http://local/r/GetSettings
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Payload::: [{"SourceId":7,"DataType":0},{"SourceId":5,"DataType":1}]
```

Comment: first thing first the console,what is its output ?

Comment: It's `method` not type, in `type: 'POST'`. See [Url](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @BCoder — type is an alias of method

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL for ajax request

AppContextRootName: Your application context root

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : '/AppContextRootName/GetSettings',
     dataType : 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I found out my issue why the Ajax call was not executing. I found out you can execute a AJAX statement while paused in the debugger!!! So don't try! It will execute and return and object but it will show pending in the network. Once you unpause the actual call is executed. You should just use Alert("Hello world") in the success and error and you will see it come back once you unpause.